# How to fill a Django table with non-query data?

Tags: python, html, django, django-tables2

I was wondering if anyone know any way to fill a Django table with data from a python file instead of from the query set?

Comment: Tried the docs? https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/table-data.html#list-of-dicts

Comment: @DBrowne Yea. That's the way that I have been building my tables. However, this time, I would like to update my table with some calculation data from a python file. So, I was wondering what would be the proper set up.

Answer (score 2):

Add it to the context from the view; let's say you have a list of dict objects generated by a function called 'data_function' ready to be passed for your table in a file named 'data.py':

```
from .data import data_function as data_for_table
def fill_table(request):
    context = {
        'data_for_table': data_for_table()
    }
    return render(request, 'app/table-template.html', context)
```

This way you could do the following from your template:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>data1</th>
        <th>data1</th>
    </tr>
    {% for data in data_for_table %}
        <tr>
            <th>{{ data.data1 }}</th>
            <th>{{ data.data2 }}</th>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I will also advise you to be way more specific with your questions; providing all related code would be way more useful and people can give you specific answers for your problems.